# How to get correlation id in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Spring Team,

The below producer is able to send the values to a kafka topic successfully.

```
@Bean
Supplier<Flux<Integer>> someProducer(){
    return () -> Flux.range(1, 10);
}
```

But..how do we get the ***correlation id*** of the message produced as we get using ***ReactiveKafkaSender***? Since the flux is subscribed by Spring internally, Is there any way to get?

Comment: Please, share more info what is `correlation id` in your meaning and it is relevant to the mentioned  `ReactiveKafkaSender`? Do you use Reactive Kafka Binder? But again: what is that `correlation id` and where do you have it?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the binder does not support getting the complete `SenderResult`, only the `RecordMetadata` of a successful send.

Please open a bug on GitHub (`spring-cloud-stream`) and reference this question.

To get the `RecordMetadata` you can use `Supplier<Flux<Message<Integer>>>` and set the `senderResult` header in the message to an `AtomicInteger<Mono<RecordMetadata>>`; it will be populated with a Mono which you can subscribe to.

There's a test here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/29c3cd7cddf9b853c57fca2b2118f1b64e5dde30/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-reactive/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/reactorkafka/ReactorKafkaBinderTests.java#L315-L323

However, I can see that this is not much use without the correlation metadata.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I think it would be a good feature to have for people following "outbox" pattern.

Comment: To get a meaningful correlation id; you will need to use the `Flux<Message<...>>` form, and set the `CORRELATION_ID` header (which will then be echoed back in the `SendResult` header).

Comment: And how that `correlation id` is used in outbox  pattern?

Comment: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html. We first store messages in a table called "outbox". then we periodically publish the messages to kafka. once published, we could store the id as confirmation id. so in the next send, we could query the messages which do not have confirmation id. ( just an example).

Comment: I went ahead and opened an issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2729

Comment: See the solution with Spring Integration: https://github.com/artembilan/microservices-patterns-spring-integration/tree/main/outbox. You don't need any confirmation since we use transactional poller on DB. Plus you always can mark record as `processed` when publish to Kafka was OK. I mean the outbox pattern does not require from us a confirmation: this sounds like some custom solution with an overhead.

Comment: This is not anything to do with a DB, it's about getting the result of a send asynchronously and correlating that result to the original record that was sent. `>when publish to Kafka was OK` - that's the problem - there is currently no way to determine success or failure.

Comment: @Artem.. Lets imaging that we use reactor sink. Spring subsribes to sink.asFlux(). So..one end is subscribed by spring. The other end application
drops the messages sink.tryEmitNext(event). I could implement my application this way too. But as soon as I drop the message via sink, it does not mean that it is sent! So SenderResult with a correlation id to give us some kind of confirmation on which message was sent would be very helpful.

Comment: Right, I see. So, since your publisher is reactive then you cannon rely on transactional DB polling. Therefore you do that manual update when you got a `sendResult` back.